# Is induction cooktop supposed to heat with pauses?

Tags: cookware, electric-stoves, induction

I came to think about this today. I was using my [Prestige Induction](https://www.mangalandmangal.com/stores/4578/prestige-induction-cook-top-pic-200.jpg) for 1 year. When the power is upto 500, the heating doesn't work continuously. It heats for 4-5 seconds, then pauses for 1 second without any error message. This didn't irritate me actually, as I thought **it is the function**. Same doesn't happen when temperature is higher than 500. Heating works continuously.

So is it really a function/feature of induction cooktops? Or is it technical problem with induction or cookware?

Answer (score 4):

It is normal for an induction burner to power cycle. I don't know about your brand specifically.

Comment: Same as a microwave, it cannot change the actual power output, so it does it in on/off steps, relying on the pan to maintain the average temperature in between pulses..

Comment: Now the thing is I Googled about it. So strange that no one has discussed it. Just showing useless results like heating problem fix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course - you obviously set the power with the plus or minus according to the heat you want. And then as you’ve seen power goes off and on again to maintain the heat you chose. Incidentally you’ll note only the bottom of the pan gets hot - not the sides of the pan